# Cart Price Rule in magento2

Tags: magento2.2, shopping-cart-price-rules, php-7

How to create a rule **Buy X get @888**?

Please explain me.

Thanks.

Comment: For this you can add tier price in product. Or if you want to do it via rule then you need to customize or create extension...

Comment: You want to give the discount or add in price?